# Linq Select all records newer than a specific date

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple query where I want to get all data where a particular date is newer than 6 years ago.

My code looks like this:

```
var dt = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-6);
return _context.ChildInfo.Where(c => c.ChildDob > dt );
```

But this is returning all records not just ones that are newer than 6 years ago from today. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit:

childdob definition

```
public partial class ChildInfo
{
    public DateTime? ChildDob { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks okay to me - I suspect this is a diagnostic problem rather than anything else. That really, really shouldn't be fetching anything older than 6 years ago...

Comment: how is `ChildDob` implemented? does it perhaps default to `DateTime.Max`? could you add minimal data structure of the `ChildInfo` class & data to reproduce?

Comment: Somehow removing the nullable attribute solved this issue.

Comment: If that solved the issue, and you want to keep the nullable attribute, yo might try `_context.ChildInfo.Where(c => c.ChildDob != null && c.ChildDob.Value > dt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that ChildDob is a Nullable.
You need:

```
return _context.ChildInfo.Where(c => c.ChildDob.HasValue && c.ChildDob.Value > dt );
```

See also:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx